# Writing query for multiple tables in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I am writing my last query for my homework, but I am stuck on it right now. This query requires me to take information from 2 tables instead of 1. I am confused on how to get this information from both tables and how to put them together. Here is the description of the query that I am trying to write.

```
Find the name, independence year, and region of all countries where English is an official language.
Order results by region ascending and alphabetize the results within each region by country name.   
(44 results)
```

Here are the tables that I am going to use for this query

```
Table "lab2.country_language"
Column    |         Type          |               Modifiers                
--------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 language     | character varying(30) | not null default ''::character varying
 is_official  | boolean               | not null default false
 percentage   | real                  | not null default 0::real
Indexes:
 "country_language_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (country_code, language)
Foreign-key constraints:
"country_language_country_code_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES country(country_code) ON    DELETE CASCADE

 => \d country
                           Table "lab2.country"
 Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers              

-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
continent       | continent             | not null
region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
indep_year      | smallint              | 
population      | integer               | not null default 0
life_expectancy | real                  |
```

Comment: [This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) might give you a clue.

Comment: Please don't delete important/relevant information from your questions after they're answered. It'll just confuse other people who come here to learn from the same things later. (I have undone your change). You might want to read the welcome guide / tour for stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in the above comment, you have to do an SQL (inner) join in this case. So you'll have something like:

```
SELECT name, indep_year, region 
FROM lab2.country 
JOIN lab2.country_language
ON lab2.country.country_code = lab2.country_language.country_code
WHERE …
```

Comment: I have one more question for ya. Do I have to use the keyword DISTINCT to find the language english in the table? or do I just do WHERE (language = "English") AND (is_official IS TRUE)

Comment: No you don't have to use DISTINCT, it's for filtering http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/

Don't forget to accept the answer if your question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be [the PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html), in particular, [joins between tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html).

You must perform an *inner join* between the two tables to link them together into a bigger virtual row that you can then filter and select individual columns from.

The tutorial provides better examples than I can.