# Query error when getting information from 2 different tables in php

Tags: php, postgresql

For my homework assignment I have to write queries from a database of information about the world. I get an error in one of my queries and I cant figure out why. The problem statement for the query that I am having trouble with is:

```
Find all official languages, the country for which it is spoken, and the percentage of speakers      
(percentage of speakers is calculated as percentage spoken times country population divided by 100). 
Order results by the total number of speakers with the most popular language first. (238 results)
```

The error that I get when I try to run my query from the website is:

```
Query failed: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "city" LINE 1: ...kers FROM lab2.country AS 
co JOIN lab2.country ON lab2.city.... ^
```

The code that I wrote for my query is:

```
 case 11:
                    $q = "SELECT name, language, ((pecentage * population)/100) AS 
percentage_of_speakers FROM lab2.country AS co JOIN lab2.country ON lab2.city.country_code WHERE  
(is_official IS TRUE) ORDER BY percentage_of_speakers DESC";

                    $result = pg_query($q) or die ('Query failed: '. pg_last_error());
                    break;
```

The information that I get for this query comes from two different tables instead of one. I believe I have to use a JOIN statement in order to get the data from both tables. Here are the 2 tables that are being used. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
 Table "lab2.country_language"
Column    |         Type          |               Modifiers                
--------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------
 country_code | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 language     | character varying(30) | not null default ''::character varying
 is_official  | boolean               | not null default false
 percentage   | real                  | not null default 0::real

                           Table "lab2.country"
 Column      |         Type          |               Modifiers                
-----------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
 country_code    | character(3)          | not null default ''::bpchar
 name            | character varying(52) | not null default ''::character varying
 continent       | continent             | not null
 region          | character varying(26) | not null default ''::character varying
 surface_area    | real                  | not null default 0::real
 indep_year      | smallint              | 
 population      | integer               | not null default 0
```

Comment: Good on you for having a proper attempt at the problem. ([Another student in the same course posted this rather poorer attempt earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25913964/398670)). In future, though, when asking for help with a homework assignment please say that it's homework.

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted your query so I could read it, but I didn't fix the problems. Here's how it looks with better formatting:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  language, 
  ((pecentage * population)/100) AS percentage_of_speakers 
FROM lab2.country AS co 
     JOIN lab2.country ON lab2.city.country_code
WHERE is_official
ORDER BY percentage_of_speakers DESC
```

The problem in the query is the two highlighted parts below:

```
FROM lab2.country AS co 
     JOIN lab2.country ON lab2.city.country_code
               ^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The first problem is that you're trying to join `lab2.country` to its self (`lab2.country AS co JOIN lab2.country`). You're actually allowed to do that in SQL, and it's really useful sometimes, but it's not what you need here. You need to join `lab2.country` to `lab2.city` instead.

The bigger problem is the `ON` expression in your join. You can't just join on a value like that. A *join predicate* (that's what the part after the `ON` keyword is called) must be an *expression* that evaluates to a *boolean value* (i.e. is true or false). It is what links the two tables together.

---

To learn how to solve this, I suggest that you study the [PostgreSQL tutorial on joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html). The linked tutorial provides an example of how this works using the example tables from the PostgreSQL tutorial (these are *not the tables in your question*):

```
SELECT *
FROM weather INNER JOIN cities ON (weather.city = cities.name);
```

See how `(weather.city = cities.name)` provides a kind of "test" expression that can be run for each combination of rows to see whether they match or not?

Hopefully that'll explain how joins work so you can understand how to fix your original query.

(By the way, I strongly recommend getting used to testing your code interactively in a tool like `psql` or PgAdmin-III. They're way more convenient than some random web based query tool, and often give better error messages.)

Comment: I tried your statement above and I get this error Query failed: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "city" LINE 1: ...kers FROM lab2.country AS co JOIN lab2.country ON lab2.city.... ^

Comment: @asdf I reformatted your query to make it readable. I didn't fix it. Read the rest of my answer, which explains what is wrong with it and how to fix it yourself. I won't do your homework for you, but I'm happy to give you some hints along the way.

Comment: I changed lab2.city.country_code to just lab2.city and I still get an error. What am I missing?

Comment: wait do I even use a city table in this query? now Im super confused haha, can you help me out?

Comment: @asdf Read the tutorial I linked to. If you are still stuck after studying it, and reading my explanation of the problem with your join's `on` clause, then let me know. Please spent an hour or so trying to solve it yourself using the documentation and tutorial first though. Maybe it'll be easier to start at the beginning of the PostgreSQL tutorial: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html as it shows the creation of the example tables.

Comment: @asdf I'd already tried to make it as clear as I possibly could that the example I gave was not just a pre-written answer to your homework. I have edited the question to further emphasise that. I hope it helps.